# How to search for text files containing a set of words (e.g., AAAA & (BBB | CCCCC) & ~DDD)?

Tags: grep, find, search, text

I need to find the files that fulfill a relatively complex condition. 
For example, I want to find all files that fulfill all below conditions:

- does contain word AAAA
- does contain word BBB or CCCCC (may contain both of them)
- does not contain word DDD

The words may appear in any order and may appear in different lines
(or the same line).

I have one solution, which combines `find` and `egrep`,
but it is not very legible.

```
find . \( -type f -and -exec egrep -q 'BBB|CCCCC' {} \; \
     -and      -exec egrep -q AAAA {} \; \
     -and -not -exec egrep -q DDD {}  \;    \) -print
```

Is there any better way to solve that problem?

Comment: How big are the files? In particular are they each small enough to sit in memory? In general you want to only read the files once, rather than 3 times. This suggests to me to  use awk/perl/python. If I stick with your approach  I would use additional flags to egrep if available. In particular `-q` to stop as soon as the match has been determined. I would use `-v` to egrep rather than `-not` in find as I consider it more readable.

Comment: Usually I need that functionality to search for certain source files (C, Python, C++) the use certain specific libraries or solutions. So the file should fit in the memory, however avoiding a necessity to read the whole file may significantly speed up the search (that's why I used -q option).

Comment: as an aside, that looks like all the actions are chained with _and_, so you shouldn't need the parentheses, or indeed the `-and`, since it's implicit between any actions if you don't specify `-or`. (Like just before the `-print`.) And as a nitpick, `-and` and `-not` aren't POSIX, the standard ones are `-a`, `-o` and `!`. So, just `find . -type f -exec grep ... \; -exec grep ... \; ! -exec grep ... \; -print` might do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your solution is pretty legible for the task, in my opinion. However, it's slow, because it spawns 3 processes per file. I reckon Awk is better suited here because it will allow to read a whole batch of files (as allowed by ARG_MAX) in a single go, using `{} +` instead of `{} \;`.

GNU Awk:

```
find . -type f -exec gawk '
    BEGINFILE{c1=c2=c3=0}
    /AAA/       {c1=1}
    /BBB/||/CCC/{c2=1}
    /DDD/       {c3=1; nextfile}
    ENDFILE{if(c1 && c2 && !c3)print FILENAME}
' {} +
```

POSIX<sup>*</sup>:

```
find . -type f -exec awk '
    FNR==1{
        if(NR>1 && c1 && c2 && !c3)print f
        c1=c2=c3=0
        f=FILENAME
    }
    /AAA/       {c1=1}
    /BBB/||/CCC/{c2=1}
    /DDD/       {c3=1; nextfile}
    END{if(c1 && c2 && !c3)print f}
' {} +
```

<sup>*Actually, `nextfile` is still not POSIX but [it has been accepted to the next issue of the standard](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607). You can remove it for POSIX issue 7 compliance; the result will be the same, but with a performance penalty.</sup>

---

**Note**: Awk bails out if it does not have permissions to read a file. In GNU Find, simply add the `-readable` flag to avoid that. If GNU Find is not available, Test can be used as an additional filter:

```
find . -type f -exec test -r {} \; -exec awk '
    ...
' {} +
```

But spawning a Test for each file represents a performance penalty.

---

Further reading:

- [POSIX Find](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).
- [POSIX Awk](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).
- [The BEGINFILE/ENDFILE special patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html).

Comment: @EdMorton That `f &&` was meant to keep the outcome correct even if someone uncritically modified the logic so as to test for only negative conditions (`!c1 && !c2 && !c3`). Ironically, it actually introduced a bug (the one you point out), so I've adopted your superior suggestion, `NR>1`. Many thanks for keeping an watchful eye on Awk answers!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way. It works by first making lists of files that contain each individual word:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -lF 'AAA' {} + > files_with_AAA
find . -type f -exec grep -lF 'BBB' {} + > files_with_BBB
...
```

Then the conditions can be implemented by processing the lists:

```
grep -xFf files_with_BBB files_with_AAA   # AAA & BBB
grep -xFvf files_with_BBB files_with_AAA  # AAA & ~BBB
sort -u files_with_AAA files_with_BBB    # AAA | BBB
```

If there is a large amount of files and multiple expressions to evaluate, this can be faster as each file does not have to be rescanned.

Comment: (1) What do you mean by “each file does not have to be rescanned”?  If there are *N* patterns, then you have to scan each file *N* times.  (2) IMHO, you don’t explain very clearly what your answer is doing and how it works.  (3) Passing lists of filenames to programs is risky and error-prone.  For example, if `file1` contains “`BBB`” and `file17` contains “`AAA`”, your command will say that `file17` contains “`AAA`” and “`BBB`”.  Consider using the `-x` option to `grep`, or maybe the `comm` program.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) The question is about a ‘‘relatively complex condition’’ with four patterns.  Your answer does not explain how to scale it to more than two patterns.  (5) Naturally, your answer will fail if filenames contain newlines.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I mean scanning each source file for words does not have to be repeated. This only needs re-reading the list of filenames, which should be a lot faster. For complex conditions, you would pipe the commands together or use temporary files. I agree on the limitation about newlines in filenames (.. which is a horrible design mistake in *nix to allow them in the first place). Added the -x.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested to see a timing comparison with these solutions,
especially for [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep),
which has built-in parallel processing.

1. With `GNU grep`

   ```bash
   grep -rLZ 'DDD' | xargs -0 grep -lZ 'AAAA' | xargs -0 grep -lE 'BBB|CCCCC'

   # if your search terms are literal strings
   grep -rLZF 'DDD' | xargs -0 grep -lZF 'AAAA' | xargs -0 grep -lF -e 'BBB' -e 'CCCCC'
   ```
2. With `rg`. 
   Note that recursive search is enabled by default
   and certain files are also ignored by default. 
   You need to use `-u` if you don't want files like `.gitignore`
   to influence the results. 
   Use `-uu` to additionally search hidden files. 
   Use `-uuu` if you want to search binary files as well.

   ```bash
   rg --files-without-match -0  'DDD' | xargs -0 rg -l0  'AAAA' | xargs -0 rg -l 'BBB|CCCCC'

   # if your search terms are literal strings
   rg --files-without-match -0F 'DDD' | xargs -0 rg -l0F 'AAAA' |
                                        xargs -0 rg -lF -e 'BBB' -e 'CCCCC'
   ```
3. With `rg` multiline matching

   ```bash
   rg -lUP '(?s)\A(?!.*DDD)(?=.*(BBB|CCCCC)).*AAAA'
   ```